# Php chatgpt: Разбить текст по предложениям в массив, но с ограничениями

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, текст, chatgpt

Отправляю текст по API в chatgpt. Но надо текст разбивать, т.к. не влазит из-за ограничений у модели.

Задача:
разбить текст в массив по предложениям. Каждый элемент массива не должен быть больше N символов и должен содержать не обрывистое предложение.

Например, предложение "При. По. К? С. Ло! Л" c максимальным числом символов 3 на элемент должно на выходе иметь массив (знаки точки, воскл и вопрос не учитываем):

```
[0] При
[1] По.К
[2] С.ЛО
```

Пытался решить:

- Сначала разбиваем на предложение через explode
- Потом ищем индексы массива, которые будут индикаторами "перебора" предложений на 1 элемент
- И уже формирую новый массив, учитывая эти индикаторы

Но в итоге застрял...может у кого-то есть уже решение, возможно проще?
Спасибо

```
$sentences = explode('.', $text); // не учел еще знаки: !, ?, ...

      $text_comp = $sentences[0];

      for ($i = 1, $size = count($sentences); $i < 5; $i++) {

          if (mb_strlen($text_comp, 'utf-8') <= $MAX_LENGTH)  {
            $text_comp .= $sentences[$i];
          }
          else {
          $remember_key[] = $i-2;
          $text_comp = $sentences[$i-1];
          $i = $i-2;
        }
      }
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r ($remember_key);
      echo '</pre>';
```